# Connecting Organisation service using CRM 2011 IFD

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am just stating to learn xRM. For most time, I will be working from out of my work network. (due to many reasons our VPS doesn't always work as expected)

I can normally connect to our CRM using IFD from my personal PC. What I want to know is that can I use the Organisation service from outside our network? If yes, do you know of any example? or is it the same standard way described on MS CRM website?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recheck following [article](http://dynamicscrmdevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/07/ifd-claims-based-authentication.html) that describes how to connect to CRM in IFD mode using C#.

Comment: Thanks Andrii. Will give this a go as soon as I get my internet connection back. (*Yes, service is down for last 3 days* Great eh!!)

Answer (score 4):

To future-proof Andrii's answer, here is the sample code from the linked article:

```
Uri organizationUriIFD = new Uri("https://[server]:[port]/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
credentials.UserName.Password = "password";

IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> config = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(organizationUriIFD);

using (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(config, credentials))
{
  // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
  _serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

  IOrganizationService _service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;

  WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)_service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
  Console.WriteLine(response.UserId.ToString());

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```